# When searching a list of specific sites in Google's Programmable Search, YouTube dominates the results. Any way to balance it among the site list?

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-search-api

I've given google's programmable search a list of sites, for now I'm starting with:

[image]

But when I search any query, I get pretty much only YouTube results, which I believe is because YouTube has the highest page rankings.

**Is there any way to customize this to be more balanced among the different sites?**

See below for more detail for what I'm thinking.

## Possible Solution #1: Round-Robin

The top result from the first site displayed, then the next site, and so on, until all sites have had their top search result displayed, then starting over.

## Possible Solution #2: Site-to-Page Rank Ratio

Let's pretend that youtube's site "rating" is a 10, and reddit's is a 5. Now, in a list of search results, let's say that youtube.com/some-result has a rating of 8, and reddit.com/some-other-result has a rating of 6. In this case, the reddit.com result should display first, even though the youtube.com result has a higher absolute ranking. The reddit page's page-to-site ratio is higher.

I have no idea if #2 would even be possible, but maybe it can serve as an illustration for what I'm looking for. I'd be plenty happy with a simple #1 Round Robin approach.